# Is there any program or library to convert html to dom mainpulation script?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, converters

I don't like using innerHTML, even it's faster.

But, I need to convert html to dom manipulation code.

Ex)

```
<div class="my-class">
    <a href="#my-link">My Link</a>
</div>
```

to

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'my-class';

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = '#my-link';
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('My Link'));
div.appendChild(a)
```

------ EDIT

I can't use jQuery because of mobile (especially android)

Comment: @Yani Yes, but as it's responsive and jQuery's dom maipulation performance is TOO slow for mobile, especially android.

Comment: @HackerK If you want higher performance, then why are you seeking a 3rd party lib.  Better do this with vanilla JS

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan I want to pre-compile(?) html to pure javascript manipulation code for better performance, and easier developement

Comment: you're saying that JS dynamically creating dom elements is faster than straight HTML?

Comment: No, but I hate innnerHTML because it's not a right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments,

it seems you're seeking [template framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9745739/1671639) (eg: check [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)) But it is entirely different where your output will be different.

Here is a list [Template-Engine-Chooser!](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/)

Comment: I don't like innerHTML and template engine (template engine just concentrate string and replace data)

Comment: @ceram1 hmm.  if not template engine then i guess there is no way unless you write your own.